# How to deploy Oracle Dimension table for OLAP Cubes

Tags: oracle, olap, olap-cube, oracle-olap

I followed [First Example](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/olap/example_1.html) as well as [Second Example](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_olap_dimensions_cubes.htm) to create Cubes in Oracle 10g.

I tried to create cube using query rewrite mechanism in Oracle 10g.

(Intailly tried to create using Analystic workspace manager we got error in that too so only we went for query rewrite mechansism)

We succeded in creating table "PRODUCTS"
Also we succedded in creating Dimension for that table "PRODUCTS"

But when we try to create Attribute for the above "PRODUCTS" table like below

```
BEGIN 
cwm_classify.remove_entity_descriptor_use(28, cwm_utility.DIMENSION_TYPE, 'SH', 'PRODUCTS');
COMMIT; 
END
```

we are getting following error.
Note : We have data inside table too

```
Error starting at line 1 in command:
begin 
cwm_classify.remove_entity_descriptor_use(28, cwm_utility.DIMENSION_TYPE, 'SH', 'PRODUCTS'); 
commit; 
end; 
Error report:
ORA-06510: PL/SQL: unhandled user-defined exception
ORA-06512: at "OLAPSYS.CWM$OLAP$DIMENSION", line 242
ORA-06510: PL/SQL: unhandled user-defined exception
ORA-06512: at "OLAPSYS.CWM$UTIL", line 368
ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at "OLAPSYS.CWM$CLASSIFY", line 322
ORA-06512: at "OLAPSYS.CWM$CLASSIFY", line 1198
ORA-06512: at line 2
06510. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: unhandled user-defined exception"
*Cause:    A user-defined exception was raised by PL/SQL code, but
           not handled.
*Action:   Fix the problem causing the exception or write an exception
           handler for this condition. Or you may need to contact your
           application administrator or DBA.
```

When i googled i got suggestion like we have to deploy Dimension also before deploying Cubes.

So i'm trying to create OLAP Cubes for this i need to to deploy Dimension Tables in Oracle.
Is there any way to deploy Dimension is that possible actually?

Suggest me how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Analytic Workspace Manager, the OLAP documentation would be a good place to start:

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/olap.112/e17123/cubes.htm#BGBDJAAG

Comment: Thanks Craig. But if i dont use Analytic workspace is it hard to accomplish my goal? suggest me ?

Comment: I believe you can use DBMS_CUBE instead, but I believe everything is much easier with Analytic Workspace Manager

Comment: i tried with Analytic Workspace too.. we got errors there too.. donno how to proceed on both.. totally stucked up Craig. Ok i will try DBMS_CUBE and get you back. Also i have edited whole post. This is my complete problem description. I hope you could help me now better